# Background on Send Events?

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send, marketing-cloud-connect

We trigger a custom Activity in a Journey based on a data extension, see setup on image below. For each data extension there is a campaign trigger sent to our API/customActivity App then.
[image: journey builder]

Since the amount of records in these data extensions can be quite large (>500k), we now want to estimate how fast and in what batches, Marketing Cloud will send out these triggers (send events?).

We have executed some performance tests and found out that 50 entries are sent out in ~3 minutes, 1000 entries are sent out in ~6 minutes and larger sets are sent out in batches of roughly ~1000 per minute.

Now I have the following questions:

1. Is there documentation available on the algorithm behind the concurrency and scaling for sending out the triggers?
2. If one trigger cannot be processed by our custom App, because the load gets too high: How can we tell Marketing Cloud to throttle its send events and repeat the failed send event? (Http Status Code TOO_MANY_REQUESTS?)
3. In which cases does Marketing Cloud repeat sending an event on failures, etc.?

Sorry in case of using wrong Marketing Cloud terminology. I am quite new to this platform.